# select onchange should change map bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

I have a select with some regions (voivodship) - if user select any - the map should change center and zoom to best fit the region. This is the theory. Now the code:

controller.js:

```
KPNControllers.controller('branchesCtrl', ['$scope', 
  function branchesCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.voivodships = [
        {"name" : 'dolnośląskie', "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.8047592,
                  "lng" : 17.7989169
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.09634,
                  "lng" : 14.816831
               }
            }},
        {"name" : 'kujawsko-pomorskie', "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 53.7809988,
                  "lng" : 19.7618465
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.33079009999999,
                  "lng" : 17.2472673
               }
            }}];
   $scope.$watch('voivodship', function() {
      if ($scope.voivodship !== undefined) {
        console.log($scope.voivodship.bounds);
        $scope.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.voivodship.bounds.northeast),new google.maps.LatLng($scope.voivodship.bounds.southwest));
        console.log($scope.bounds);
        $scope.map.panToBounds($scope.bounds);
        $scope.map.fitBounds($scope.bounds);
      }
    })
```

partial/branches.html:

```
<select ng-model="voivodship" ng-options="voivodship.name for voivodship in voivodships" class="full-width"><option value="">-- wybierz województwo --</option></select>
```

unfortunately map doesn't change and console shows:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First - you can't user $scope.voivodship.bounds.northeast as source of LatLng - it's owful, but you have to use new google.maps.LatLng($scope.voivodship.bound.northeast.lat,$scope.voivodship.bound.northeast.lng) (maybe someone can make it nicer?)

And second one - the look carefully into doc - the LatLngBounds constructor: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pl&csw=1#LatLngBounds

LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng, ne?:LatLng)

first is sw not ne - if you do it wrong - it sends you into space ;D

the proper code:

```
 $scope.$watch('voivodship', function() {
    if ($scope.voivodship !== undefined) {
      $scope.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new  google.maps.LatLng($scope.voivodship.bounds.southwest.lat,$scope.voivodship.bounds.southwest.lng), new google.maps.LatLng($scope.voivodship.bounds.northeast.lat,$scope.voivodship.bounds.northeast.lng));
        $scope.map.panToBounds($scope.bounds);
        $scope.map.fitBounds($scope.bounds);
  }}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's better to go to sleep or for a walk and goes back with fresh mind ;D